# How to retrieve Java vendor information

Tags: java

How can I retrieve Java vendor information without having to compile and run following script:

```
import java.util.Properties;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            Properties prop = System.getProperties();
            System.out.println ("JVM Vendor : " + prop.getProperty("java.vendor") );
    }
}
```

I couldn't find it in command line options.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Note: The following will work for the Oracle JVM - not tested on others. (To get details on non-standard options execute `java -X`)

You can use the non-standard `-XshowSettings` flag to show all settings, or alternatively `-XshowSettings:properties` to show all property settings.

So for example if you execute the following command:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

This will show you all properties one of which is `java.vendor`. Not sure if it is possible to get it to output just a single property though.

Comment: Following error is comming:Unrecognized option: -XshowSettings:properties
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: I generally run on linux, but have just tried it on a Windows machine and it works just as well there. Setups were: Ubuntu 12:Oracle Java 1.7.0_17. Windows 7: Oracle Java 1.7.0_25. Running `java -X` will give you details on non-standard options, where `-XshowSettings` is listed, at least for the version of Java from Oracle.

Comment: For Oracle Java version it works nice. Any chance to get only one property at once? On Linux it would be pretty easy to grep just this option but on Windows.

Comment: Yes I have only tested with the Oracle JVM. Have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar -XshowSettings is a nonstandard flag. Also it's only present in Oracle JREs from version 1.8 (Java 8). (Probably not that important now that it's 2021 and pre-8 Java versions are not supported.)

Answer (score 6):

If you have any running java app 'jinfo' is your friend:

```
Usage:
jinfo [option] <pid>
    (to connect to running process)
jinfo [option] <executable <core>
    (to connect to a core file)
jinfo [option] [server_id@]<remote server IP or hostname>
    (to connect to remote debug server)

where <option> is one of:
-flag <name>         to print the value of the named VM flag
-flag [+|-]<name>    to enable or disable the named VM flag
-flag <name>=<value> to set the named VM flag to the given value
-flags               to print VM flags
-sysprops            to print Java system properties
<no option>          to print both of the above
-h | -help           to print this help message
```

So

```
jinfo -sysprops <pid of javaprocess> | grep "java.vendor = "
```

gives you the system property.

[Beware](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

> Also note that the value of system properties can be overwritten! For example, if myProperties.txt contains the following line, the java.vendor system property will be overwritten:
>
> java.vendor=Acme Software Company

Comment: TBH no chance that this property will be changed in my case :)

Answer (score 4):

You may use below command

```
$ java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

Below is good blog on JAVA properties for Linux and Windows

[Retrieve JAVA properties & Version information](http://www.weblogitech.com/2015/03/how-to-get-java-vendor-information-and-version-properties.html)

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: This is why a *good* answer includes the relevant content in the answer as linked external resources can disappear at any time.

Answer (score 2):

If it's JDK run jvisualvm, open VisualVM app, go to "System properties" tab

Comment: I need console way to do it unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

if it's Tomcat goto: TOMCAT_HOME/bin/

and then execute the version.sh file (*e.g. ./version.sh).